# Can I put two GTX Titan X GPUs in a Dell T7400

Tags: gpu, dell-precision

I have a Dell T7400, I can take out the Quadro that is in it if necessary, can I put two Titan Xs into it? Will the motherboard support it? And the power supply?

Comment: I'm sure you have a good reason for it, but I wonder if you could scrounge up something a *little* more modern. a 2-3 generation old core i7 (or better yet, a modern one!)would probably give you the same performance for much more efficiency. We have 2x2 core T7400s and they run *hot*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There are two PCIe x16 (Ver. 2) slots available on the motherboard so there will be no problem fitting in two Titan Xs if you take out the Quadro.

A single [Titan X](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-titan-x/specifications) utilizes 250 W of power and Nvidia recommends a minimum of 600 W system power. So two of those cards will use around 500 W and depending on the rest of your system a minimum of 1000 W PSU might be required. (I think that the T7400 packs in a 1000 W PSU). And you will be needing 2x 6-Pin and 2x 8-Pin PCIe connectors to power two of those cards (1x 6-pin + 1x 8-pin for each Titan X).

Comment: I think this may be incorrect, after some more research it looks like the power supply on the T7400 can't handle larger cards without adapters for the power to split amps between cables. http://boogerfling.com/blog/2012/09/09/dell-precision-t7400-workstation-will-not-power-up-with-ati-radeon-5970-installed-problem-solved/

Comment: Keep in mind that the T7400 is PCIe 2.0, and the Titan X is PCIe 3.0.  It will still work but may limit the performance of the cards.

Comment: @pjreddie Yes I was not sure about the PSU that comes with T7400 that is why I mentioned the minimum wattage required and the cable configuration. I did a little search on the T7400's PSU to check out its capacity. But I will suggest to go for a new PSU.

Comment: @Jason Yes I was going to mention that about the PCIe 2.0 and 3.0 part but since compatibility isn't  much of an issue and all the GPU manufactures has adopted PCIe 3.0 standard for their latest cards so I dropped that point. But its worth mentioning though. Thanks!